# Setting WQHD resolution in text mode

Tags: fedora, grub2, nvidia, resolution, kms

This is an yet another question about setting higher resolution in text mode, **but I've already tested some solutions posted on U&L and unfortunatelly with no effect.**

Let's start at the very beginning:
I've fresh (up to date) copy of Fedora 24 with Nvidia proprietary drivers installed and WQHD monitor (resolution 2560 x 1440):

```
uname - r
4.7.4-200.fc24.x86_64

nvidia-settings --version
370.28
```

In the past, with lower monitor resolution (1280 x 1024) and nouveau drivers I simply added *vga=795* parameter and it was working properly.

Now I have resolution exceeding max VGA (1600x1200) and Nvidia drivers, thus this could cause problems with Kernel Mode-Setting.

In GRUB2 console, I've check the code of desirable resolution:

```
set pager=1
insmod vbe
vbeinfo

2560x1440 x32  ->  0x14d
2560x1440 x16  ->  0x14c
2560x1440  x8  ->  0x14b
```

Because, 0x14d (hex) is 333 (dec) I've naively tried to pass *vga=333* and *video=333*. Of course, this approach misfired.

I have also tried to add the following two lines to the `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=2560x1440x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=2560x1440x32
```

After GRUB2 update `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` every *menuentry* was supplied with line `set gfxpayload=2560x1440x32` and the *load_video* function loads *VBE*:

```
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}
```

After that I cannot even see anything in text mode, pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 it shows completly black terminal without any promt, completly nothing.

The last thing I've tried, was installing *FBSET*, but I get the following error:

```
open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
```

**Could I have 2560x1440 in text mode with Nvidia drivers (needed for CUDA dev)?**